# How would I (programmatically) set the height of a UITextView to its content size in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` called `recipeDesc`. I would like to have an option within my app to dynamically adjust the height of the `UITextView` to fit the content (text) inside the `UITextView` (so I need to know how to do it programmatically). I found some answers for Objective-C, but I am not very familiar with it, so I don't know how to implement it in Swift.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16):

You can get the ideal content size for your `UITextView` simply with:

```
let contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
```

So after that, you can adjust it's frame with that height:

```
var frame = textView.frame
frame.size.height = contentSize.height
textView.frame = frame
```

(I originally had used `textView.contentSize.height` but that does not work when the view has not rendered yet. For example in `viewDidLoad`)

If you use Auto Layout, the rules are a bit different. Update your question if you do.

Comment: I have also some troubles and I use autolayout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431968/how-to-adjust-the-height-of-a-textview-to-his-content-in-swift I tried to use your code but it doesn't work in my case.