# Size of UITextView after setting its height depending of its content SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview, frame

I have a UITextView, with a height constraint in order to adapt the height of the frame to its content (depending of the length of the string). (I use autolayout). It works fine.

[image: caseA] [image: caseB]

But, I don't understand something about the size of the textview frame.

I explain.

I display the frame infos after setting the text of the uitextview, and after updating the constraint.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.textview.text = post.title
    ...
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    let contentSize = self.textview.sizeThatFits(self.textview.bounds.size)
    self.heightConstraint.constant = contentSize.height
    self.textview.layoutIfNeeded()

    print(self.textview.frame) // frame
    print(self.textview.bounds) // bounds
}
```

The result:

For case A:

```
(8.0, 0.0, 584.0, 97.0) //frame
(0.0, 0.0, 584.0, 97.0) //bounds
```

For case B:

```
(8.0, 0.0, 584.0, 97.0) //frame
(0.0, 0.0, 584.0, 97.0) //bounds
```

I don't understand why the height of the frame is the same in both case???

Comment: Show us your constraints. You should not need to update any constraint in code to get the result you want to, if they're correctly set up (with compression and hugging priorities correctly set).

Comment: Is there any special case you are using an UITextView instead of an UILabel?

Comment: Yes, because I need to use exclusionPaths on the textContainer, around the back button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to adjust the height of a textview to his content in SWIFT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431968/how-to-adjust-the-height-of-a-textview-to-his-content-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem if you don't need the scrolling part of the `UITextView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let textView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(self.textView)
        self.textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.textView.text = "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world"

        self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.textView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.textView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor).active = true
        self.textView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.rightAnchor).active = true

        self.textView.scrollEnabled = false // magic which will help auto expanding 
    }
}
```